# Can I make an array of variables in Java?

Tags: java, pointers

Based on another setting, I have a list of variables that need to be set to elements of an array. How can I make this succinct, without pointers?

Example: I have a string with chess moves and variables startRow, startCol, endRow, endCol, color, piece (all strings).

The data comes from a string which I split into String[] bits.

But if the associated type is "A" then the string is

```
startRow, startCol, endRow, endCol, color, piece
```

but if the type is "E" then the string is

```
piece, color, startRow, endRow, startCol, endCol
```

I have variables of the same names. I can do

```
case "A":
    startRow = bits[0];
    startCol = bits[1];
    (etc)
case "E":
    startRow = bits[2];
    startCol = bits[4];
    (etc)
```

But I'd like

```
Vars[] av = {startRow, startCol, endRow, endCol, color, piece};
Vars[] ev = {piece, color, startRow, endRow, startCol, endCol};
```

and set Vars[] allv to either one and loop:

```
allv[i] = bits[i];
```

C (or PHP) is not an option!

Comment: what is the type of different variables - `startRow`, `startCol`, `endRow`, `endCol`, `color` etc?

Comment: what do you mean by the associated type?

Comment: Your question is unclear, but it's worth nothing that, in Java, an array already *is* a container of variables. `allv[0]` is a variable exactly as much as `startRow` is a variable. What you *don't* have in Java are "variable variables", or the ability to "alias" one variable to another. What you can do instead is have more than one reference variable refer to the same *object*, which perhaps is what you're trying to do here? But it's not completely clear to me.

Comment: Yug: as I said, all strings. mousahalaseh: the variable that guides the choice. switch (on that assoc var) case "A": case "E", etc. Daniel: probably right, but unfamiliar technique to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `startRow`, `startCol`, etc. are fields (as opposed to local variables), you can write an anonymous function for each field that has the behavior of assigning the value of its argument to the field.

E.g.

```
List<Consumer<String>> aSetters =
  Arrays.asList(
    s -> startRow = s,
    s -> startCol = s,
    s -> endRow = s,
    s -> endCol = s,
    s -> color = s,
    s -> piece = s);

List<Consumer<String>> eSetters =
  Arrays.asList(
    s -> piece = s,
    s -> color = s,
    s -> startRow = s,
    s -> startCol = s,
    s -> endRow = s,
    s -> endCol = s);

List<Consumer<String>> setters; // initialize to aSetters or eSetters accordingly

for (int i = 0; i < bits.length; i++) {
  setters.get(i).accept(bits[i]);
}
```

An alternative to using the anonymous functions `s -> color = s` is to use a method reference to the setter for that field, if one is available (e.g. `this::setColor`).

If `startRow`, etc. are local variables, there isn't really a good way to do this because Java doesn't let you assign to local variables from anonymous functions. There are some nasty hacks, like replacing each variable with an array of length 1 and assigning to the 0th element of the array from the anonymous function, which is allowed, but this can be very confusing to read.

Comment: Excellent. I upvoted but being new, my vote doesn't count. :(

Comment: If you feel like it satisfactorily answers your question, you can mark it as accepted (but no pressure) :)

Comment: It's worth noting that the reason it works for fields is because the `this` reference is automatically closed over by each lambda, and the `this.` qualifier can be omitted from a field name. It might be slightly clearer to say `s -> this.startRow = s` etc.; up to you. Note that, prior to Java 8, passing around a `this` reference had to be explicit, but the same basic principle applies. You have two references (the "outer" and "inner" versions of `this`, in the case of a lambda) that both point at the same object, so mutations to the object through one reference can be read through the other.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I'm still a bit fuzzy on the new J8 stuff, except to know I am impressed by streams, lambda, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I propose as a solution, without checking for errors and ranges of values
(this is only schema/idea):

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] mask_A = {1,2,3,4,0};
        int[] mask_B = {2,3,0,4,1};
        String[] source = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(setMask(source,mask_A)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(setMask(source,mask_B)));
    }
    public static String[] setMask(String[] source, int[]mask) {
        String[] result = new String[mask.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < mask.length; i++) {
            result[i] = source[mask[i]];
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Results:
[B, C, D, E, A]
[C, D, A, E, B]

Other way, with Enum:

```
import static logging.ExampleLogging.Case.*;
public class ExampleLogging {
    public enum Case {
        A, B, C, D, E
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Case[] mask_A = {A,B,C,D,E};
        Case[] mask_B = {C,D,A,E,B};
        String[] source = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(setMask(source,mask_A)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(setMask(source,mask_B)));
    }
    public static String[] setMask(String[] source, Case[]mask) {
        String[] result = new String[mask.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < mask.length; i++) {
            result[i] = source[mask[i].ordinal()];
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but it doesn't help if the actual desire is to be able to refer to each of those values by a name. You could create constants with the various names, so that you would refer to the values in practice as something like `values[START_ROW]` instead of `startRow`; there are pros and cons to that approach as well.

Comment: Ok. may be Enum with its method ordinal(). enum[] mask = {enum_A, enumB.... e.t.}  and in loop use result[i] = source[mask[i].ordinal()];